# ERROR at line 91: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" in oracle 10g

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, procedure

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALCULATE_CURVE(E_YEAR IN NVARCHAR2,E_TERM IN  SMALLINT,LECTURE_ID IN NVARCHAR2)                                         
   IS CURSOR C1 IS 
   SELECT STUDENT_CODE, AVERAGE
   FROM TRANSCRIPT
   WHERE TERM=E_TERM AND YEAR=E_YEAR AND LECTURE_CODE=LECTURE_ID
   FOR UPDATE;
   STUDENT_ID  NVARCHAR2(10);
   AVR  NUMBER;
   E_GRADE NVARCHAR2(3);
   AA INTEGER; 
   BA INTEGER;
   BB INTEGER;
   CB INTEGER;
   CC INTEGER;
   DC INTEGER;
   DD INTEGER;
   FD INTEGER;
   AVRAGE NUMBER(5,2);
   SD NUMBER(5,2);
   DIFF2 NUMBER(5,2);
   N NUMBER(5,2);
  BEGIN
   SELECT AVG(AVERAGE) INTO AVRAGE
   FROM TRANSCRIPT 
   WHERE TERM=E_TERM AND YEAR=E_YEAR AND LECTURE_CODE=LECTURE_ID;
   SELECT SUM(POWER(AVERAGE-AVRAGE,2)), COUNT(*) INTO DIFF2,N
   FROM TRANSCRIPT 
   WHERE TERM=E_TERM AND YEAR=E_YEAR AND LECTURE_CODE=LECTURE_ID;
   IF N>=30 THEN
   N:=N-1;
   END IF;
   SELECT SQRT(DIFF2/N) INTO SD FROM DUAL;
   OPEN C1;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LECTURE_ID);
   AA:=AVRAGE+2*SD;
   IF AA>90 THEN 
   AA:=90;
   BA:=AVRAGE+3*SD/2;
   IF BA>85 THEN
   BA:=85; 
   BB:=AVRAGE+SD;
   IF BB>80 THEN
   BB:=80; 
   CB:=AVRAGE+SD/2;
   IF CB>75 THEN
   CB:=75;    
   CC:=AVRAGE;
   IF  CC>70 THEN
   CC:=70;  
   DC:=AVRAGE-SD/2;
   IF DC>60 THEN
   DC:=60;  
   DD:=AVRAGE-SD;
   IF DD>50 THEN
   DD:=50;  
   FD:=AVRAGE-3*SD/2;
   IF FD>40 THEN
   FD:=40;
   LOOP

   FETCH C1 INTO STUDENT_ID,AVR;
   EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
   IF AVR>=AA THEN
   E_GRADE:='AA';
   ELSIF AVR>=BA THEN
   E_GRADE:='BA';
   ELSIF AVR>=BB THEN
   E_GRADE:='BB';
   ELSIF AVR>=CB THEN
   E_GRADE:='CB';
   ELSIF AVR>=CC THEN
   E_GRADE:='CC';
   ELSIF AVR>=DC THEN
   E_GRADE:='DC';
   ELSIF AVR>=DD THEN
   E_GRADE:='DD';
   ELSIF AVR>=FD THEN
   E_GRADE:='FD';
   ELSE
   E_GRADE:='FF';
   END IF;

   UPDATE TRANSCRIPT 
   SET GRADE=E_GRADE
   WHERE TERM=E_TERM AND YEAR=E_YEAR AND LECTURE_CODE=LECTURE_ID AND         STUDENT_CODE=STUDENT_ID;

   END LOOP;
   CLOSE C1;
  END;
```

the code gives the following error message: ERROR at line 91: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" the oracle mentions that before the update statement there is a missing semicolon.In my database i have transcript table which is has schema like : ID,TERM,LECTURE_CODE,STUDENT_CODE,MIDTERM,FINAL,AVERAGE,GRADE.
NOTE: i have examined each select statement externally by giving variables needed values thus no error  excited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening a series of `IF` statements that you don't close, from `IF AA>90 THEN` to `IF FD>40 THEN`. Each of those needs its own `END IF;`, probably immediately after the single statement following it, though it's possible you intended some nesting.

```
   AA:=AVRAGE+2*SD;
   IF AA>90 THEN 
     AA:=90;
   END IF;
   BA:=AVRAGE+3*SD/2;
   IF BA>85 THEN
     BA:=85; 
   END IF;
   BB:=AVRAGE+SD;
   ...
   FD:=AVRAGE-3*SD/2;
   IF FD>40 THEN
     FD:=40;
   END IF;
```

Problems like this would be a bit easier to spot if you indented your code.

When you get to the final `END;`, the compiler is telling you that it is out of place. You can't have a plain `END` at that point, the only valid thing to start with `END` is an `END IF` to close one of the `IF` blocks you opened much earlier.

Incidentally, you could use `CASE` in pace of the `IF`/`ELSIF` construct. And you could simplify the earlier `IF` blocks a bit with the `LEAST` function; instead of:

```
   AA:=AVRAGE+2*SD;
   IF AA>90 THEN 
     AA:=90;
   END IF;
```

you could do:

```
    AA := LEAST(AVRAGE+2*SD, 90);
```

Comment: simply it works..many thanks!! @Alex poole :)
 that code was edited from microsft sql  server sytax to oracle syntax  i got too many conflicts